# Failure to get a positive integer

Tags: python, integer

Here is the code that I've written:

```py
number = int(input('Enter a nonnegative integer: '))

product=1
for i in range(number): 
    product = product * (i+1)
    print(product)
```

The result is:

```py
1
2
6
24...
5040
```

But I only need the resulted nonnegative integer when the input is `7`, which is `5040`. How do I get that?

Comment: Python is a language that deals with indentation a lot. Looking at your own code, do you think it's possible for anyone to decipher how your code is formatted?

Comment: You only need the nonnegative integer of 7 which is 5040... what does this sentence mean? Please have a look at your question, and edit it such that anyone can easily read it.

Answer (score 1):

Unindent the print statement so it's not in the for loop. Then it will only print the result.

```py
number = int(input('Enter a nonnegative integer: '))

product=1
for i in range(number):
    product = product * (i+1)
print(product)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and it was also giving me an error for having a space after the : in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have fix your indentation. Let's make a function named `make_product` that achieves your goal.

```py
def make_product():

    # take input
    number = input('Enter a nonnegative integer: ')

    # strip whitespace of the input string
    number = number.strip()

    # convert to positive integer
    number = int(number)

    product=1
    for i in range(number):
        product = product * (i+1)

    return product
```

Use the function like this:

```py
make_product()
```

If you enter 7 into the prompt, this should show 5040. Moreover, even if there is extra whitespace in your input, the program will be able to handle that.